# Мусорный unicode при попытке копировать файл оканчивающийся на \n С

Tags: c, файлы, копирование, текстовые-файлы

есть цикл который проходится построчно и копирует текст из одного файла в другой. Возникла проблема, когда файл заканчивается на \n, то появляется мусорный юникод. При отладке понял что буфер полон \r\r\r\r... Не совсем понимаю почему так происходит и как это исправить

код:

```
   do{
        _buf = (char*)malloc(_bufsize * sizeof(_buf));
        _pbuf = fgets(_buf, _bufsize , _res_file);

        if(!_pbuf && !feof(_res_file)){

            ERR("read file err");

            fclose(_res_file);
            fclose(_temp_file);

            return NULL;
        }


        fprintf(_temp_file, "%s", _buf);

        #ifdef DEBUG
            fprintf(stderr, "%d%s%s", _line++, "\t -| ", _buf); // на последней пустой строке мусорный юникод 
        #endif

        free(_buf);
        _buf = NULL;

    }while(!feof(_res_file));
```

вывод консоль:

```
** E:\project\FileManageC\res\text123.temp **
1        -| 12345678910
2        -| 2
3        -|
4        -| 4
5        -|
6        -| 6
7        -|
8        -|
9        -| 9
10       -|
11       -| 11
12       -| 12
13       -| 13
14       -|
15       -|
16       -| 16
17       -|
18       -| 18
19       -|
20       -| 20
21       -|
22       -|
23       -| 23
24       -|
25       -| 25 25 25 25 25
Ён║лллллллллллллллл
```

вывод файл:

```
12345678910
2

4

6


9

11
12
13


16

18

20


23

25 25 25 25 25 

�
�
�
�
�
... на 1000+ строк
```

Comment: Вы когда malloc выделяете память, она там не чистыми 0 забита! calloc очищает 0 ;) Попробуйте завести переменную "счетчик", которая будет считать сколько байт вы прочитали в буфер. Поймете мусор из файла или в буфере. Ибо в коде нет взятия размера файла и создание буфера от его размера. Так же посмотрите в HEX режиме конец файла, который вы читаете. Может там мусор? При !feof() последним приходит 0xFF и иногда его записывают.

Comment: @FrancNet спасибо огромное, помогло замена malloc на calloc.

Comment: Хотите реально быстро -- используйте [mmap](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). / А так, тривиальный `while ((c = fgetc(_res_file) != EOF) fputc(c, _temp_file);` не будет драматически медленнее вашего цикла. / Ну, в крайнем случае, если надо ускориться, а mmap в системе не реализован, то делайте цикл из `read(...) / write(...)` с мегабайтным блоком